# The point estimate and the large sample size

Tags: sample, population, point-estimation

My colleagues and I argued about the point estimate's accuracy. They said that

**"The point estimate will tend to be accurate if the sample size exceeds 30."**

While I am saying no,

**"The point estimate is always a subject to error as we will never know the population value"**

Which is the correct one?

Comment: What do you mean with 'accurate'? Unbiasedness? Since you come up with the 'n > 30', I guess you are thinking in the way of the Central Limit Theorem which says that the mean  is unbiased. Now assuming your point estimate should represent this mean, there is still error. Unbiasedness means that if you repeat your experiment very often, calculate your point estimate and take the mean of all these point estimates, then it will be very close to the population value. However, if you just take one sample and calculate a point estimate, this value might not be even close to this population value.

Comment: @Mathemagician777 Yes, that is what my colleagues think about. They believed it was because of the CLT. So, any large sample size will result in a very small sampling error without any conditions.

Comment: The question is too vague and depends a lot on what one considers as 'accurate'. It is also unclear what the actual discussion point is. The second statement has little to do with the first statement, or at least it is unclear why it should be a reason that the first is wrong. Potential related questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22all+models+are+wrong%22

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thank you for your comment and the link. My colleague argues that the large sample size, without any conditions, reduces the sampling error. I don't see it this way, as there must be conditions, such as the sampling method.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The question is very clear about which statement is correct. I do respect your comment, but I think the question is should not be closed.

Comment: @Dr.Alenezi I do not follow your comments. Are you saying with your first comment that your question is about a the statement whether a larger sample size leads to better estimates? How does this relate to the text which speaks about two unrelated statements and asks is to judge which one is correct? The second comment I do not understand. How is it an argument or explanation that it should not be closed? (btw. the close reason that you read is 'question needs to be more focused' but I voted to close the question because it is 'opionion based')

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I do respect your point of view. However, I believe it is not an opinion based". It is a theory, logic, and knowledge. Is it OK to teach a student, or inform someone, that a large sample size is enough to ensure a small sampling error and that the point estimate is very close to the real value?! without any conditions!

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus "How does this relate to the text which speaks about two unrelated statements and asks is to judge which one is correct?"  Are they unrelated, and why? Someone believed that the first statement is universally true,  while I said no, it is not; there are some conditions. So, I asked which opinion was correct. This may help statistics learners to understand this point. That is why the question should not be closed. If you do not understand it, maybe someone else can help. Our opinions can be different, but other people may learn something new.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus It is OK to vote down or vote to close the question, however, we should learn from each other and have a good discussion as good scholars and that may help others. I just try to explain my point of view. However, in the end, I do respect you and your opinion.

Comment: *"however, we should learn from each other and have a good discussion as good scholars and that may help others"* When it comes to the question and answer format on stackexchange this should be done with clear and focused questions. If questions are unclear then people will be answering based on wrong assumptions or different opinions about what a question is intended to be. To avoid such noise, questions are being closed such that they can be improved before the answering process starts. It makes no sense to keep unclear questions around, these will do more harm than being helpfull.

Comment: *"However, I believe it is not an opinion based. It is a theory, logic, and knowledge."* A problem is that the question is unclear and the interpretation of the question itselve is opinion based. For example, there are many trivial examples where estimators do not improve or even become worse when the sample size increases (e.g. the sum of the sample as a silly estimator for the mean $\hat\mu_x = \sum_{i}^n x_i$). But, the rule of thumb about samples of size 30 might be useful in many situations. We will have to guess what is meant with it in order to answer the question in a non-trivial way.

Comment: *" Are they unrelated, and why? Someone believed that the first statement is universally true, while I said no, it is not; there are some conditions."* In the question you say more something like "it is not; the point estimate is always false". That's a different thing than speaking about conditions.

Comment: *"Is it OK to teach a student ... ? without any conditions!"* This seems like a different question than the one you ask (about which of the two statements are correct), but this type of question would be especially opinion based. Whether it is ok to teach like that probably depends a lot on the particular class, field, curriculum and background. When rules of thumb are taught, like "larger samples = better estimates", then this can be done without stating all the exceptions. Whether it is ok is not a statistical question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both, really, at least, in some conditions. But also neither, in some conditions.

Your statement is correct, unless we actually *do* know the population value. This can happen if the population is small and easily defined. E.g "what is the average age of full time professors in NYU's psychology department?"  But usually, your statement is right, we have a sample and do not know the population value perfectly.

However, if you have a random sample, then the accuracy goes up as sample size increases, and, for some distributions, 30 is reasonably accurate (for some definition of "reasonably"). How much accuracy you need varies by application.

But it also depends what you are estimating.  It's easier to estimate the mean than the 90th percentile (for most distributions, anyway).

EDIT  On the other hand, if you do not have a random sample, it doesn't matter how big your sample is. The most infamous example of this is the Literary Digest poll of the 1936 presidential election. They polled tens of millions of people and got millions of response and confidently predicted that Dewey would beat FDR in a landslide. But, FDR actually won one of the biggest landslides of any presidential election. What went wrong? The magazine polled subscribers to the magazine, car owners, and phone owners. In 1936 this was a *very* biased sample.

Comment: Great! Your help is fantastic.  I appreciate it so much. However, do you know how about the sampling method? It affects the result, even if the sample size is large enough. For example, if I have a sample of 35 students with low grades, does that mean the average of the whole class (say 200 students) will be low? No, it is not. It depends on my sample. That is my point.

Comment: OK, I said "if your have a random sample" but I will add more about that.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is so much appreciated.